# How to return raw response from JavaLite.io activeweb controller

Tags: javalite, activeweb

It is possible to return raw response from JavaLite.io Activeweb controller without chaining it with embedded FreeMarker template engine ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is easy:

```
public void index() {
   respond("{\"success\":true}").contentType("application/json").statusCode(200);
}
```

In other words, the method `respond()` will do exactly what you need.